# is there another samples of php foreach?

Tags: php, foreach, sample

I looking for another samples of php foreach code that similar to the code as following:

```
foreach ($this->ask->post['books'] as $book) {
    if ($book['qty']) {
        $this->goto->add($book['book_id'], $book['qty'], (isset($book['opt'])) ? $book['opt'] : NULL);
    }
}
```

I just want to save it as my collection, so, is there another samples of php foreach that You may know? let me know it. Thanks

Comment: Update [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102712/another-sample-of-my-php-foreach) instead of reposting. It's still not understandable what you want. You won't get any helpful answers if you don't invest some time in your question phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this example can help you:

```
foreach($myArrayOfObject as $key=>$object) {
    if($object->aPropertyOfMyObject) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

You can also have a look to http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: thanks for the reply, so regarding to my code it could be: '**foreach($this->ask->post['books'] as $key=>$book) {
    if($book->$this->ask->post['books']) {
        // do something...
    }
}**' let me know if i do something wrong.

Comment: You're `if(...)` is wrong.

It should be  `if($book['foo'] == 'bar')` where foo is a key in the array book and bar a value to compare.

or

`if($book->foo == 123)` where foo is a property of the object $book

Comment: OK thanks, then the another samples code of: `$this->goto->add($book['book_id'], $book['qty'], (isset($book['opt'])) ? $book['opt'] : NULL);` is there another samples that may i see?

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need foreach?

You can also use this:

```
<?php

$array = array(); // Imagine a filled array
array $max = count($array);

for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++) {
 // Loop over the array
 echo $array[$i]['name_of_key']; 
}

?>
```